# perl + Irregular Expression (VALID IP + ADD Valid Rule)

Tags: perl

the following  syntax is part of perl script with Irregular Expression
as we see the target of the following syntax is to get VALID IP address
as 123.33.44.5 or 255.255.0.0 etc

but how to change the following syntax if I want to valid also the IP:

for example:

```
  124.33.*.*
```

(I want to valid also the * character as valid number 1-255)

example of valid IP's

```
*.1.23.4

123.2.*.*

*.*.*.*

*.*.198.20
```

example of not valid IP's

```
 123.**.23.3

 289.2.2.2

 21.*.*.1000

" *.*.*.**"
```

#

my orig code:

```
my $octet = qr/[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]/; 

my $ip = qr/ \b 
         (?!0+\.0+\.0+\.0+\b) 
         $octet(?:\.$octet){3} 
         \b 
       /x;
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what you want is to start with the string `"124.33.*.*"` and derive a new regex that will match that (transforming the `"*"`s to a regex that matches `1` through `255`)?

Comment: I mean that "*" is like the rule 1-255 so for example "*.*.*.*" is valid and "1.1.1.*" also valid and "*.255.255.*" also and etc -:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. Need to add "*" to octet definition.
2. Much worse - "*" matches word boundary (\w). So you should instead use explicit character class for ip-boundary: `[^\d*]`

   ```
   my $octet = qr/[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[*]/; 
   my $ip = qr/\b0+\.0+\.0+\.0+\b|(?:[^\d*]|^)$octet(?:[.]$octet){3}([^\d*]|$)/x;

   foreach $str (@ip_list) { 
       print "$str - ";
       print "NO " if $str !~ $ip;
       print "match\n";
   }
   ```

OUTPUT:

```
1.1.1.1 - match
123.1.*.* - match
1.*.3.4 - match
*.192.2.2 - match
23.*.3.3 - match
*.1.23.4 - match
123.2.*.* - match
*.*.*.* - match
*.*.198.20 - match

123.**.23.3 - NO match
289.2.2.2 - NO match
21.*.*.1000 - NO match
*.*.*.** - NO match

11.12.13.14 - match
1.*.3.4 - match
1.*.3.* - match
0.00.0.0 - match
```

Comment: @DVK: 1.*.3.4 its also valid IP , the "*" char can located as "*.xxx.xxx.xxx" as valid IP or as "XXX.*.xxx.xxx" as valid IP etc

Comment: for example all the follwoing are valid as "*.12.3.4" or "87.*.3.3"

Comment: the "*" char can be in between the . *  . and this is valid

Comment: @DVK can you make the little change in your code in order to support my needs?

Comment: yes but I need also to support for example the "*.192.2.2" or "23.*.3.3" etc

Comment: from some reason its not match the "*.10.10.10" why ?

Comment: I found the problem - `\b` in the original regex was the culprit. Fixed.

Comment: what to say exelent work , I dont have words to say like to tauch the sky ....................very very good

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do this? you should instead use proper CIDR notation, e.g. 124.33/16, and then you can use standard Net::IP::* modules to handle the IP ranges.

Comment: because on my system files I have also the IP as example 128.2.*.*

Comment: the target of my code is to match all valid IP's include IP's with *

Comment: please give me feedback if you understand my answer

Comment: @jon: my point is that your system files should not specify IP address ranges in this manner - it is non-standard.

Comment: I see  but our file configuration is fit for our needs so its not meter if it standard or not , and we cant change files rules ,

Comment: So subclass `Net::IP`, to accept this format. It isn't hard. `my $count = ( $ip =~ s/(?:\.\*)//g ); $ip .= '/' . (8*$count) if $count`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub is_ip_with_wildcards {
    my ($ip) = @_;
    my @octets = split / [.] /xms, $ip;    
    return 4 == grep { $_ eq q{*} || m/ \A [0-9]+ \z /xms && $_ < 256 } @octets;
}

while( defined( my $line = <> ) ) {
    if( my @ips = grep { is_ip_with_wildcard( $_ ) } split q{ }, $line ) {
        print 'found IPs: ', join(q{, }, @ips), "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are called regular expressions (not Irregular Expressions).

If you want a specific prefix, you could just say

```
my $octet = qr/[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]/
my $ip = qr/\b124[.]33[.]$octet[.]$octet\b/;
```

A warning about your regex though, as of Perl 5.8 `\d` no longer matches just `[0-9]`.  Instead it matches and Unicode digit character, so the string `"①.①.①.①"` will match as will `"᠐.᠐.᠐.᠐"` (which is even worse, since that is `0.0.0.0` in Mongolian).  Always use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` unless you want such matches.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub wildcard_to_regex {
    my $wildcard = shift;
    my @octets   = split /[.]/, $wildcard;

    for my $octet (@octets) {
        next unless $octet eq "*";
        $octet = qr/[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]/;
    }

    my $regex = '\b' . join("[.]", @octets) . '\b';
    return qr/$regex/;
}

for my $wildcard (qw/8.8.8.8 *.*.*.0 1.1.1.* 1.1.*.1/) {
    my $regex = wildcard_to_regex($wildcard);

    print "$wildcard\n";
    for my $test (qw/1.1.1.0 1.1.1.1 1.1.2.1/) {
        print "\t$test ",
            $test =~ $regex ? "matched" : "didn't match", "\n";
    }
}
```

It prints

```
8.8.8.8
        1.1.1.0 didn't match
        1.1.1.1 didn't match
        1.1.2.1 didn't match
*.*.*.0
        1.1.1.0 matched
        1.1.1.1 didn't match
        1.1.2.1 didn't match
1.1.1.*
        1.1.1.0 didn't match
        1.1.1.1 matched
        1.1.2.1 didn't match
1.1.*.1
        1.1.1.0 didn't match
        1.1.1.1 matched
        1.1.2.1 matched
```

Comment: I think that's not what the user wanted. They want the string `124.33.*.*` to match the regex.

Comment: @DVK I read "I want to valid also the * character as valid number 1-255" as meaning he or she wants the place held by * to be a valid number between 1 and 255.  Of course, that means my answer is still incomplete because the original `$octet` regex matches `0`.

Comment: so I will wait for you , I want to see the completed answer thanks for your help

Comment: @jon I updated it right after I made that comment (I added `$octet` instead of having you use the version in your original code).

Comment: sorry but this is not the point , the target is to search in file system valid IP's and they can be also with star "*" as "*.123.3.3"

Answer (score 0):

This should be obvious, but subclass `Net::IP`. Here I subclass it to `SillyIP`, and wrap the `set` function. In real life I'd probably subclass this to `Net::IP::SillyIP` though.

```
package SillyIP;
use Moose;

extends 'Net::IP';

around 'set' => sub {
  my ( $orig , $self, $ip, @args ) = @_;

  die "invalid IP" if $ip =~ /\*{2}|\s/;

  if ( $ip =~ /\.\*/ ) {
    my $count = ( $ip =~ s/(\.\*)+$/.0/g );
    $ip .= '/' . (abs(4- $count)*8);
  }

  $self->$orig( $ip, @args );

};

1;

package main;

use Test::More tests => 5;

eval { SillyIP->new('10.**.1.1') };
ok ( $@, 'Fail to accept **' );

eval { SillyIP->new(' 10.0.1.1 ') };
ok ( $@, 'Fail to accept spaces in ip' );

is ( SillyIP->new('10.*.*.*')->ip, SillyIP->new('10/8')->ip, '8 bit network' );
is ( SillyIP->new('192.168.*.*')->ip, SillyIP->new('192.168/16')->ip, '16 bit network' );
is ( SillyIP->new('192.168.1.*')->ip, SillyIP->new('192.168.1/24')->ip, '24 bit network' );
```

This will provide 90% of what you're asking. It doesn't however accept `*` as a range for digit. This is because ipv4 addresses aren't decimal. They're actually just a 32bit data structures, which can be displayed as `a.b.c.d` so long as `{a,b,c,d}` is in range of 1-255 (8 bits). This means that asking `*.1.2.3`, to represent `1.2.3.4`, and `2.2.3.4`, but not `1.2.3.5` has no technical merit whatsoever. There is no reason to ever need this. But you could accomplish it with a quick binary algorithm.

Comment: TIMTOWTDT and all, but this introduces a new class, imports Moose, AND Net::IP; and has 11 new lines of code. Versus 2 lines of code when doing it via RegEx (4 lines if you want to wrap the regex into a sub)... Wee bit of an overkill, IMHO, while not having ANY of the benefits of pre-canned CPAN library (e.g. widely tested/reliable) due to having roll-your-own code anyway.

Comment: Well, you're categorically wrong here. Subclassing claims **ALL** of the benefits of the module you're sub-classing, less any problems you introduce -- to claim otherwise just shows a profound misunderstanding of OO. Your solution can lead one to believe that it is ok to treat non-strings, as strings which just isn't so. It isn't even OK to treat HTML -- which is kind of a string -- as a string. Regexes don't belong in some places -- this is a great example of where you should stay away from them. And, SLOC has nothing to do with *overkill*: you're the one reimplimenting IP validation.